# Write mathematical formulas in HTML

Tags: html

I wanted to make an HTLM page that focuses on physics, with a calculus based physics.  It will eventually show problems, with a way to derive a solution.  One concern I have is that math notation often has subscripts or super scripts.  for example when doing limits they always have a subscript on them to define the variable, as well as what it is approaching,  cant even do that in this page here, or dont know how, but how can I use proper math notation (the greek characters are not hard to get) including the proper character set as well as subscript and superscript.

An example problem I would draw out is to put a hot wheels system on a table with a slope (where the car starts) and a loop (it has to pass through) and then initally put a stopper at the end to prevent the car from falling.   by applying physics, I can estimate the minimum height needed to hit the top of the loop and fall off, at the very top of the loop.   then I would want to add 2 cm to the height, and take off the stopper at the other end.  but apply calculus to solve the motion equation to approximate where the car would crash as it fell off the table.

I would want the student to apply this kind of method to derive the formula for themself, and I would then validate the formula.  After the formula was agreed to match, I would then have them fill in the variables needed, and to place a mat to catch the car.  if they caught it on 1st try it would be an A, on 2nd try it would be a C and anything else would basically be an F (as in they are not learning enough yet to move to the next level)

I want them to learn to apply the math and do it well enough to solve it right the first time (not by trial and error.

Well this was a long drawn out question, but id like to know how to get proper formatting of math notation  in html? or am I better off using some other tool, and having it display as a graphic as opposed to text?

Comment: This is far too broad a question and very vaguely defined. Is this about adding a subscript to a variable, or writing Schrödinger equation nicely, or taking any user input and parsing it as an expression and showing it and letting the user work with it? Perhaps you should just teach the students to use http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 4):

I am just going with this part of the question

*I wanted to make an HTLM page that focuses on physics, with a calculus based physics.*

[Use MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/chapter2.html)

```
<math>
<mrow>
  <mi>A</mi>
  <mo>=</mo>
  <mfenced open="[" close="]">
    <mtable>
      <mtr>
         <mtd><mi>x</mi></mtd>
         <mtd><mi>y</mi></mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
         <mtd><mi>z</mi></mtd>
         <mtd><mi>w</mi></mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
  </mfenced>
</mrow>
</math>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xm9B/)

Comment: you always rock yaaar :)

Comment: Won’t work on most browsers, and even MathML-aware browsers support just part of MathML. Adding MathJax would improve support considerably—and also make it unnecessary to use a notation as complicated as MathML in most cases.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yea, surely MathJax is a way to go but at the end, its MathML

Comment: Nope, MathJax is software that interprets a subset of MathML *and* a subset of LaTeX/AMSTeX *and* simple linearized math notation.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I meant to say, you type mathml, mathjax takes care of the rest, so op needs to learn mathml anyways... mathjax than wraps each character using `span` to position them

Comment: And my points were that 1) without MathJax (or something similar), MathML is not a feasible solution on the Web, and 2) using MathJax, you don’t need MathML; compare e.g. the LaTeX notation `$$\begin{bmatrix}x & y \\ z & w\end{bmatrix}$$` with the tag verbosity in your example.

Answer (score 0):

`<sup>` and `<sub>`, respectively. If you're looking only for super- and sub-scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<sub></sub>
<sup></sup>
```

Reference site about <sub>Lorem Ipsum</sub> giving information on its origins.

Reference site about <sup>Lorem Ipsum</sup> giving information on its origins.